# Find the fundamental matrix of a system of ODEs?

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, systems-of-equations

To linearize a system, in one of the steps I am required to find the fundamental matrix $\Phi$(t) of a system such that $\Phi$(0)=I. The example system my professor used:

$\dot{x} = x - y - x^3 - xy^2$

$\dot{y} = x + y - x^2y - y^3$

$\dot{z} = \lambda z$

Then $\vec\gamma(t) = (\cos{t}, \sin{t}, 0)^T $ is a periodic orbit of the system.

We compute $D\vec f(\vec x)= \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1-3x^2-y^2 & -1-2xy & 0 \\
1-2xy & 1-x^2-3y^2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \lambda \end{array} \right)  $

Then the linearization is given by $\frac{d}{dt}\vec x=A(t)\vec x $ where

$A(t) = D\vec f(\vec\gamma(t)) =  \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
-2\cos^2{t} & -1-\sin^2{t} & 0 \\
1-\sin^2{t} & -2\sin^2{t} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \lambda \end{array} \right)$

This all makes sense until he says "Clearly, this is its fundamental matrix:"

$ \Phi(t) =  \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
e^{-2t}\cos{t} & -\sin{t} & 0 \\
e^{-2t}\sin{t} & \cos{t} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & e^{\lambda t} \end{array} \right)$

Am I missing something? How does one get from the periodic matrix A(t) to the fundamental matrix?

Comment: What I _want_ to say is that $\Phi(t)=\exp{(A(t)t)}$ since this would give the lower RH-element immediately. But that giving the $2\times 2$ block in $\Phi(t)$ isn't immediately obvious to me.